# Does using std::get on std::array give better performance?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, get, c++17

The Standard Library class template `std::array<T, N>` has both a member accessor function

```
constexpr const T& operator[]( size_type n ) const;
```

as well as a non-member accessor function template

```
template< size_t I, class T, size_t N >
constexpr const T& get( const array<T,N>& a ) noexcept
```

In C++17, all the `operator[]` overloads have been made `constexpr`, so I wonder what, if any, are the remaining advantages of `std::get`. E.g. in a program like this:

```
int main()
{
    auto a = std::array<int, 3> { 1, 2, 3 };
    constexpr auto idx = 0;
    std::cout << a[idx] << '\n';
    std::cout << std::get<idx>(a) << '\n';
}
```

any decent compiler should be able to propagate the constant index value `0` for both `operator[]` and `get`.

**Question**: what benefits does `std::get` on `std::array` give that `operator[]` doesn't?

Comment: One benefit is it allows `std::array`s to be used in many places where a `std::tuple` is expected

Comment: Performance wise there shouldn't be any difference AFAIK; assuming your compilers optimizer does its job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get is required for structured bindings.

Other generic tuple code will also use it.

Comment: Ah yes, the structured binding is a good point. But since `get` just delegates to the `op[]` with a compile-time constant, there should not be any performance difference in other contexts, right?

Comment: @TemplateRex Play with [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/GIVzYe), and you will know

Answer (score 3):

> Question: what benefits does `std::get` on `std::array` give that `operator[]` doesn't?

In addition to providing a common interface with tuple, which is apparently how we're implicitly generically defining product types in C++, `std::get` does have one more advantage. Bounds checking at compile time:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr;
arr[4] = 17;           // bad
std::get<5>(arr) = 42; // bad, but also compile error, so actually good
```

That's because the tuple interface is explicitly ill-formed if the index is out of bounds (see [[array.tuple]](http://eel.is/c++draft/array#tuple)), but `operator[]` is just a runtime problem you have to track down.